# express methods having strange behaviors

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i have routes with the get method.

```
app.get("/info/teachers", controller1);

app.get("/info/teachers/:teacherid", controller2);
app.get("/info/students", controller3);
app.get("/info/students/:studentid", controller4);
app.get("/info/courses", controller5);
app.get("/info/courses/:courseid", controller6);

app.get("/info/courses/enrolled/:studentid", controller7);
app.get("/info/assists/teachers", controller8);
app.get("/info/assists/teachers/:teacherid", controller9);
app.get("/info/courses/:teacherid", controller10);

app.get("/info/assists/students", controller11);
app.get("/info/assists/students/:studentid", controller12);
```

all of them works except for app.get("/info/courses/:teacherid", controller10);

but if i move his position to:

```
app.get("/info/teachers", controller1);
app.get("/info/courses/:teacherid", controller10);

app.get("/info/teachers/:teacherid", controller2);
app.get("/info/students", controller3);
app.get("/info/students/:studentid", controller4);
app.get("/info/courses", controller5);
app.get("/info/courses/:courseid", controller6);

app.get("/info/courses/enrolled/:studentid", controller7);
app.get("/info/assists/teachers", controller8);
app.get("/info/assists/teachers/:teacherid", controller9);
app.get("/info/assists/students", controller11);
app.get("/info/assists/students/:studentid", controller12);
```

it just works; why is this happening? all the controllers works independtly and dont need information from the others.

Comment: Do you really enumerate your controllers? Give them proper names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no distinction between `/info/courses/:teacherid` and `/info/courses/:courseid`. The router will pick the first that matches, and they both match the same urls.

In your second snippet, `controller6` will never be called.

You'll either need to change that route to something like `/info/courses/taught/:teacherid` (like you did with `/enrolled`), or you'll need to have a single route `/info/courses/:someId` with a controller that can distinguish whether `someId` is a teacher id or a course id. (Different prefixes, maybe?)